# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined after upgrade of React Native

Tags: react-native

I have the following js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input';
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';
import CodeField from 'react-native-confirmation-code-field';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance';
import TNActivityIndicator from '../../truly-native/TNActivityIndicator';
import TNProfilePictureSelector from '../../truly-native/TNProfilePictureSelector/TNProfilePictureSelector';
import CountriesModalPicker from '../../truly-native/CountriesModalPicker/CountriesModalPicker';
import { IMLocalized } from '../../localization/IMLocalization';
import { setUserData } from '../redux/auth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import authManager from '../utils/authManager';
import { localizedErrorMessage } from '../utils/ErrorCode';
import TermsOfUseView from '../components/TermsOfUseView';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config';
import dynamicStyles from './styles';

const SmsAuthenticationScreen = (props) => {
  const appConfig =
    props.navigation.state.params.appConfig ||
    props.navigation.getParam('appConfig');
  const appStyles =
    props.navigation.state.params.appStyles ||
    props.navigation.getParam('appStyles');

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const styles = dynamicStyles(appStyles, colorScheme);

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isPhoneVisible, setIsPhoneVisible] = useState(true);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(false);
  const [countriesPickerData, setCountriesPickerData] = useState(null);
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
  const [profilePictureURL, setProfilePictureURL] = useState(null);
  const [countryModalVisible, setCountryModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const myCodeInput = useRef(null);
  const phoneRef = useRef(null);
  const recaptchaVerifier = React.useRef(null);
  const firebaseConfig = firebase.app().options;

  const { isSigningUp } = props.navigation.state.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (phoneRef && phoneRef.current) {
      setCountriesPickerData(phoneRef.current.getPickerData());
    }
  }, [phoneRef]);

  const onFBButtonPress = () => {
    authManager
      .loginOrSignUpWithFacebook(appConfig.appIdentifier)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.user) {
          const user = response.user;
          props.setUserData({ user });
          props.navigation.navigate('MainStack', { user: user });
        } else {
          Alert.alert(
            '',
            localizedErrorMessage(response.error),
            [{ text: IMLocalized('OK') }],
            {
              cancelable: false,
            },
          );
        }
      });
  };

  const signInWithPhoneNumber = (userValidPhoneNumber) => {
    setLoading(true);
    authManager.onVerification(userValidPhoneNumber);
    authManager
      .sendSMSToPhoneNumber(userValidPhoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)
      .then((response) => {
        const confirmationResult = response.confirmationResult;
        if (confirmationResult) {
          // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
          setVerificationId(confirmationResult.verificationId);
          setIsPhoneVisible(false);
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          // Error; SMS not sent
          setLoading(false);
          Alert.alert(
            '',
            localizedErrorMessage(response.error),
            [{ text: IMLocalized('OK') }],
            { cancelable: false },
          );
        }
      });
  };

  const signUpWithPhoneNumber = (smsCode) => {
    const userDetails = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      phone: phoneNumber,
      photoURI: profilePictureURL,
    };
    setLoading(true);
    authManager
      .registerWithPhoneNumber(
        userDetails,
        smsCode,
        verificationId,
        appConfig.appIdentifier,
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.error) {
          Alert.alert(
            '',
            localizedErrorMessage(response.error),
            [{ text: IMLocalized('OK') }],
            { cancelable: false },
          );
        } else {
          const user = response.user;
          props.setUserData({ user });
          props.navigation.navigate('MainStack', { user: user });
        }
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const onPressSend = () => {
    if (phoneRef.current.isValidNumber()) {
      const userValidPhoneNumber = phoneRef.current.getValue();
      setLoading(true);
      setPhoneNumber(userValidPhoneNumber);
      if (!isSigningUp) {
        // If this is a login attempt, we first need to check that the user associated to this phone number exists
        authManager
          .retrieveUserByPhone(userValidPhoneNumber)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.success) {
              signInWithPhoneNumber(userValidPhoneNumber);
            } else {
              setPhoneNumber(null);
              setLoading(false);
              Alert.alert(
                '',
                IMLocalized(
                  'You cannot log in. There is no account with this phone number.',
                ),
                [{ text: IMLocalized('OK') }],
                {
                  cancelable: false,
                },
              );
            }
          });
      } else {
        signInWithPhoneNumber(userValidPhoneNumber);
      }
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        '',
        IMLocalized('Please enter a valid phone number.'),
        [{ text: IMLocalized('OK') }],
        {
          cancelable: false,
        },
      );
    }
  };

  const onPressFlag = () => {
    setCountryModalVisible(true);
  };

  const onPressCancelContryModalPicker = () => {
    setCountryModalVisible(false);
  };

  const onFinishCheckingCode = (newCode) => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (isSigningUp) {
      signUpWithPhoneNumber(newCode);
    } else {
      authManager.loginWithSMSCode(newCode, verificationId).then((response) => {
        if (response.error) {
          Alert.alert(
            '',
            localizedErrorMessage(response.error),
            [{ text: IMLocalized('OK') }],
            { cancelable: false },
          );
        } else {
          const user = response.user;
          props.setUserData({ user });
          props.navigation.navigate('MainStack', { user: user });
        }
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }
  };

  const phoneInputRender = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <PhoneInput
          style={styles.InputContainer}
          flagStyle={styles.flagStyle}
          textStyle={styles.phoneInputTextStyle}
          ref={phoneRef}
          onPressFlag={onPressFlag}
          offset={10}
          allowZeroAfterCountryCode
          textProps={{
            placeholder: IMLocalized('Phone number'),
            placeholderTextColor: '#aaaaaa',
          }}
        />
        {countriesPickerData && (
          <CountriesModalPicker
            data={countriesPickerData}
            appStyles={appStyles}
            onChange={(country) => {
              selectCountry(country);
            }}
            cancelText={IMLocalized('Cancel')}
            visible={countryModalVisible}
            onCancel={onPressCancelContryModalPicker}
          />
        )}
        <Button
          containerStyle={styles.sendContainer}
          style={styles.sendText}
          onPress={() => onPressSend()}>
          {IMLocalized('Send code')}
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  };

  const codeInputRender = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <CodeField
          ref={myCodeInput}
          inputPosition="full-width"
          variant="border-b"
          codeLength={6}
          size={50}
          space={8}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          cellProps={{ style: styles.input }}
          containerProps={{ style: styles.codeFieldContainer }}
          onFulfill={onFinishCheckingCode}
        />
      </>
    );
  };

  const selectCountry = (country) => {
    phoneRef.current.selectCountry(country.iso2);
  };

  const renderAsSignUpState = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{IMLocalized('Create new account')}</Text>
        <TNProfilePictureSelector
          setProfilePictureURL={setProfilePictureURL}
          appStyles={appStyles}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={styles.InputContainer}
          placeholder={IMLocalized('First Name')}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={(text) => setFirstName(text)}
          value={firstName}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />

        <TextInput
          style={styles.InputContainer}
          placeholder={IMLocalized('Last Name')}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={(text) => setLastName(text)}
          value={lastName}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />
        {isPhoneVisible ? phoneInputRender() : codeInputRender()}
        <Text style={styles.orTextStyle}> {IMLocalized('OR')}</Text>
        <Button
          containerStyle={styles.signWithEmailContainer}
          onPress={() =>
            props.navigation.navigate('Signup', { appStyles, appConfig })
          }>
          {IMLocalized('Sign up with E-mail')}
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  };

  const renderAsLoginState = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{IMLocalized('Sign In')}</Text>
        {isPhoneVisible ? phoneInputRender() : codeInputRender()}
        <Text style={styles.orTextStyle}> {IMLocalized('OR')}</Text>
        <Button
          containerStyle={styles.facebookContainer}
          style={styles.facebookText}
          onPress={() => onFBButtonPress()}>
          {IMLocalized('Login With Facebook')}
        </Button>
        <Button
          containerStyle={styles.signWithEmailContainer}
          onPress={() =>
            props.navigation.navigate('Login', { appStyles, appConfig })
          }>
          {IMLocalized('Sign in with E-mail')}
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
          <Image
            style={appStyles.styleSet.backArrowStyle}
            source={appStyles.iconSet.backArrow}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {isSigningUp ? renderAsSignUpState() : renderAsLoginState()}
        {isSigningUp && (
          <TermsOfUseView tosLink={appConfig.tosLink} style={styles.tos} />
        )}
        <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
          ref={recaptchaVerifier}
          firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
        />
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      {loading && <TNActivityIndicator appStyles={appStyles} />}
    </View>
  );
};

export default connect(null, {
  setUserData,
})(SmsAuthenticationScreen);
```

I receive the following error and stack after I upgraded to the latest version of React Native:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SmsAuthenticationScreen`.

```
This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ScrollView.js:1124)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1260)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1286)
    in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:517)
    in KeyboardAwareScrollView (at SmsAuthenticationScreen.js:340)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SmsAuthenticationScreen.js:339)
    in SmsAuthenticationScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by ForwardRef(CardSheet))
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at src/index.native.js:111)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.js:136)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by Context.Consumer)
    in CardStack (created by KeyboardManager)
    in KeyboardManager (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:31)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackView)
    in StackView
    in Unknown (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
    in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (at create-redux-container.js:93)
    in NavigatorReduxWrapper (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by MenuProvider)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by MenuProvider)
    in MenuProvider (at App.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at NativeAppearance.tsx:4)
    in FallbackAppearanceProvider (at src/index.tsx:70)
    in AppearanceProvider (at App.js:46)
    in Provider (at App.js:45)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

I have tried things that other articles and stackoverflow requests have mentioned, but no luck so far.  Somewhat new to React Native, so could be missing something easy.

Another permutation of the error:

```
    ERROR    Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or 
you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SmsAuthenticationScreen`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SmsAuthenticationScreen.js:339)
    in SmsAuthenticationScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by ForwardRef(CardSheet))
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at src/index.native.js:111)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.js:136)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by Context.Consumer)
    in CardStack (created by KeyboardManager)
    in KeyboardManager (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:31)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackView)
    in StackView
    in Unknown (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
    in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (at create-redux-container.js:93)
    in NavigatorReduxWrapper (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by MenuProvider)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by MenuProvider)
    in MenuProvider (at App.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at NativeAppearance.tsx:4)
    in FallbackAppearanceProvider (at src/index.tsx:70)
    in AppearanceProvider (at App.js:46)
    in Provider (at App.js:45)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "prettier": "prettier --write '*.js' 'src/**/*.js'",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android": " cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.7.1",
    "@skele/components": "^1.0.0-alpha.40",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "expo-av": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "^8.1.0",
    "expo-camera": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "^8.1.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase": "7.19.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "i18n-js": "^3.7.1",
    "invert-color": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-haste-map": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-serializer": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-worker": "^25.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "mobx": "^5.14.0",
    "mobx-react": "^6.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.4",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-button": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.32.3",
    "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-keyboard-input": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-tracking-view": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-patch": "git+https://github.com/HarvestProfit/react-native-modal-patch.git",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.9",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-search-box": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-nightly.5",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "7.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.8.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^4.0.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "uuidv4": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Another variation of the same error: This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SmsAuthenticationScreen.js:339)
    in SmsAuthenticationScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)

Comment: I have narrowed this down to 2 different components.  The first is, in fact, the KeyboardAwareScrollView.  For now, I'm just using ScrollView.  The second is FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal - if I change KeyboardAwareScrollView to ScrollView, and remove FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal, it renders

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade only your react-native version, then a quick cache cleaning and module reset should be fine:

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Comment: Agreed, if you are only having this issue after updating versions try a clean install

Comment: I always remove node_modules when doing updates, and I also always run "npm start --reset-cache" when testing the app

Comment: @ChrisEaheart can you update your question by including your package.json file? I will try to replicate the same issue.

Comment: @Nostromo I just updated the question - sorry for the delay

Comment: Hello, @ChrisEaheart, I gave it a try and created a new rn app with your package.json. It worked successfully but due to some missing code references in your app.js, i removed them and only left a simple text component within KeyboardAwareScrollView. Maybe this is the reason it worked on me. My other suggestion about this case is to recreate your ios and android folders based on your new package.json since you said that you upgraded from an old rn version.

Comment: Hi @Nostromo, what missing code references are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I mean since i don't have such files in your original code like ../utils/authManager or ../../localization/IMLocalization, i commented them and the other codes that depend on them out.

Answer (score 2):

From your log, the error seems to appear due to the `KeyboardAwareScrollView` module. Upon quick search on the github repo of this module, I found out the following: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/443

The issue is still not fixed but there are workarounds available in the above link which you can try. I would just uninstall `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` and install this fork which fixes this issue:

```
npm i @codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
```

Comment: Hi @manishg - I actually updated to the latest version of that package, and the stack trace changed.  Can you look at the latest permutation above of the stack trace and let me know your thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Also, just to be clear - I tried installing that other module.  It did not help - I got the same error as above (see the latest permutation of the error at the bottom of my post)

Comment: Does the error persist if you uninstall the keyboard-aware-scroll-view and remove mentions of it in your code?

Comment: @ChrisEaheart, as mentioned by you in the comments to your question, The issue is due to `KeyboardAwareScrollView` and `FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal` right? So if you remove `FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal` and use `@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` does it work?

Comment: @manishg - if I remove FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal and just use ScrollView, it works.  However, @codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view does not work, even without FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal

Comment: maybe try npm install https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#v0.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`

You can use `react-native-input-scroll-view` in ios and use `ScrollView` in android

```
import InputScrollView from 'react-native-input-scroll-view';


       {Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
          <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.subContainer}>{children}</View>
          </ScrollView>
        ) : (
          <InputScrollView>
            <View style={styles.subContainer}>{children}</View>
          </InputScrollView>
        )}
```

Comment: ScrollView does not work with FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal.  ScrollView without FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal does work - at least on Android.  I haven't tried iOS yet.

Comment: Did you try to use `react-native-input-scroll-view`